# How to get XML Object direct from IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

how can I parse a IFormFile (xml file) to an XML Object?. To deserialize it I need the xml as a string. How can I create a xml string from an IFormFile?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<MyResponse> Upload([FromForm] IFormFile xmlFile)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        
    }
    ...
}
```

My XML Model:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlType("ProductLines")]
public class ProductLinesExtentionResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProductLine")]
    public List<ProductLine> ProductLine { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ProductLine")]
public class ProductLine
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Components")]
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Component")]
public class Component
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Component")]
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go without a `string`, just pass the `stream` of the `IFormFile` directly to the [`Deserialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer_Deserialize_System_IO_Stream_) method of the `XmlSerializer`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<MyResponse> Upload([FromForm] IFormFile xmlFile)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductLinesExtentionResult));
    var productLinesExtentionResult = serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile.OpenReadStream());

    // ...    
}
```